# Laravel controllers in sub folders

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks, controller

I'm new to Laravel and want to move controllers in subfolders WITHOUT namespaces, I googled it but not found answer, that works for me. Also, I'm on HostGator shared hosting and can't install composer (to do "composer dump-autoload"), because it needs to copy phar file to /usr/local/bin and on shared hosting you don't have permissions.

I hope that someone will help.
Sorry for bad English

Comment: You should add controller's directory to composer.json autoload object

Comment: But if I have home/MainController.php and admin/MainController.php how to call admin controller and not home?

Comment: Without namespacing them, you can't.

Comment: @DaveMorrissey, Namespaces are not problem, but I have to add all classes like this: use Auth; use View; use Post; and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Regarding installing on a shared host, this is not straightforward but the guide below may work for you. If you don't have SSH access you need to run composer locally and FTP everything to the host.

HostGator's docs say they do have MCrypt, so you're in luck there.

http://driesvints.com/blog/laravel-4-on-a-shared-host/

Comment: I have SSH access, I run php composer.phar install but then composer dump-autoload says, that composer not found

Comment: You can run composer with the full path (e.g. `/path/to/composer.phar install`).

Comment: That's not problem. Problem is, that I don't want to write "use View; use Auth;" and so on for each class.